# What happened to my gravatar?

Tags: support

My gravatar, which I never updated since I joined the site when it first started, has now suddenly changed.  What happened?

Comment: I don't think there's any promise from SE that the automatically generated one stays consistent. If you want a specific one, upload it yourself.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284097/166155

Comment: If you really want the old one back save it from the wayback machine https://web.archive.org/web/20130310065048/http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5/seth-j

Comment: @DoubleAA It's not changing my life, but in looking around there seems to be something funny going on.

Comment: If you're interested in moving to a static image of your choice, here's a suggestion: https://pixabay.com/p-27018/?no_redirect It's in the public domain.